# Force Maven clean

Tags: java, maven-2, release

I have a project with 2 profiles, because UAT and PROD use different versions of the same jar.

I have noticed that if i don't explicitly call `mvn clean ...` the deployed EAR will have BOTH UAT and PROD jars.

Is there a way in the POM to specify that Maven should always clean before any building?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `maven-clean-plugin` with the `initialize` phase as given here

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Visit the [Maven clean plugin usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html), they provide an example how to run the plugin automatically during build.

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on [the maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
especially the package lifecycle.

The maven clean plugin you use will probably allow you to define a clean goal at a particular pahse.
You can also execute for example mvn clean install -P profile

Comment: i'm currently manually specifying the clean goal on the command line, since we can deploy to PROD from maven, forgetting `clean` might cause indeterminate behavior.